# Animation in UIView follow UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have work with animation same image

[image]

I have make a UILabel on UIView. And I make animation for UILabel move from right to left.

**I want same here:**

[image]

This is my code:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
             _lbAnimation.frame=CGRectMake(0-(rect.size.width), _lbAnimation.frame.origin.y, rect.size.width, _lbAnimation.frame.size.height);

         } completion:^(BOOL finished)
          {
              _viewAnimation.hidden = YES;
          }];
```

**And now, I want while frame of UILabel move to end is width of UIView: *_viewAnimation* follow UILabel.**

Please help me.

**This is my code**

https://github.com/nhhthuanck/Alert-Animation

Please check again help me.

Comment: I didn't get your last comment

Comment: I want while frame of UILabel move to end is width of UIView: _viewAnimation follow UILabel.

Comment: So you want to move view also?

Comment: I want resize UIView

Comment: So you can use transform property to resize view.

Comment: I want only decrease width of UIView, not tranform it.

Comment: I have update mu question, please check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160765/discussion-between-easy-soft-and-mangesh-murhe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put `lbAnimation` inside `viewAnimation`. And need some calculate duration of animation time.

```
- (IBAction)startAction:(id)sender {

    NSString * htmlString = @"<html>"
    "  <head>"
    "    <style type='text/css'>"
    "      body { font: 16pt 'Gill Sans'; color: #1a004b; }"
    "      i { color: #822; }"
    "    </style>"
    "  </head>"
    "  <body>Here is some <i>formatting!</i> <a href='#'><font color='green'>Google</font></a><font color='red'> example text</font><a href='#'>YouTube</a><b> bold</b> and <i>italic</i></body>"
    "</html>";
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                    initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                    documentAttributes: nil
                                    error: &err];

    _viewAnimation.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, _viewAnimation.frame.origin.y, _viewAnimation.frame.size.width, _viewAnimation.frame.size.height);
    _viewAnimation.hidden = NO;
    _lbAnimation.hidden = YES;
    CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(FLT_MAX, _lbAnimation.frame.size.height)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  animations:^{
        _viewAnimation.frame=CGRectMake(0, _viewAnimation.frame.origin.y, _viewAnimation.frame.size.width, _viewAnimation.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         _lbAnimation.hidden = NO;
         _lbAnimation.attributedText = attrStr;
         _lbAnimation.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, _lbAnimation.frame.origin.y, rect.size.width, _viewAnimation.frame.size.height);

       CGFloat duration = 6;
       CGFloat ratio = _viewAnimation.frame.size.width / (rect.size.width + _viewAnimation.frame.size.width);

       [UIView animateWithDuration:duration * ratio delay:duration * (1-ratio) + 0.1f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
         _viewAnimation.frame = CGRectMake(_viewAnimation.frame.origin.x, _viewAnimation.frame.origin.y, 0, _viewAnimation.frame.size.height);
       } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         _viewAnimation.hidden = YES;
       }];

       [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
         _lbAnimation.frame=CGRectMake(-rect.size.width, _lbAnimation.frame.origin.y, rect.size.width, _lbAnimation.frame.size.height);

       } completion:^(BOOL finished)
        {

        }];

     }];
}
```

You can check [my demo](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/alert-animation).

Comment: Now it's easier to help you. Wait a moment.

Comment: Can i use `constraints` instead of `frame` to resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes, Please make all you can.

Comment: @EasySoft i have updated my answer, you can replace your `startAction` with my method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I replaced my method by your method, but it not run. How about for your source?

Comment: @EasySoft Sorry my bad. I have updated answer with my source. You can check it.

Comment: Welcome @EasySoft ;)